How can i write jasmine unit tests for document visibility changed event
I am subscribing for the document's visibilityChanged event.Below is the code. Document is injected using dependency injection.
ngOnInit(){
        fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange')
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.checkSessionOnVisibilityChange();
        });
}

checkSessionOnVisibilityChange() {
        if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
            this.callVisible();
        } else {
            this.reset();
        }
    }

I am writing jasmine unit test and trying to mock the document like as below and providing it. But while accessing "visibilityState", the UT throws error as
"TypeError: Cannot set property document of [object Window] which has only a getter"
const documentObj = {
        visibilitychange() {
            return of({});
        },
        visibilityState(){
            return 'visible';
        }
    };

What is the way to mock document evets and properties properly and use in the testing module. Is the way i am doing is correct?
